# Query from a array and count the query result in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a keywordsList table has two columns, like this:

```
id | keywords 
-------------
1  | [apple cake, apple pie, apple cookie]
-------------
2  | [banana cake, banana juice]
-------------
3. | [orange candy]
```

I want to query the string which match anything in keywords columns and count how many result that I search successfully.
For example, I search "apple", and I want to get the result like this:

```
id | keywords                              | totalCount
-------------------------------------------------
1  | [apple cake, apple pie, apple cookie] |  1
```

I want to get the result shows that which array match "apple", and how many rows I got.
This's code that I try to get that result:

```
SELECT DISTINCT "id", "keywords", COUNT("id") OVER () as totalCount 
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT *, unnest("keywords") AS "unnestKeywords" FROM "keywordsList") AS "keywordsList" 
WHERE "unnestKeywords" ILIKE "%apple%"
```

But I get the result like this:

```
id | keywords                              | totalCount
-------------------------------------------------
1  | [apple cake, apple pie, apple cookie] |  3
```

I could get correct id and keywords columns, but couldn't get correct count.
Hope to get any suggestion. Thanks

Comment: I think you want to use DISTINCT in your COUNT `COUNT(DISTINCT "id")`, BTW can you make certain to post correct queries because I highly doubt `"apple"` is correct shouldn't that be `'%apple%'`

Comment: @Eelke Yes, I actually want to use DISTINCT in COUNT, but sql will throw error. Thanks for your remind, `"apple"` won't work.

Comment: It's unclear to me if you want to count the number of times a keyword occurs in a single array, or in all rows. What is the expected result if the search keyword is `'cake'`?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name sorry for unclear. I want count the number of all rows. If search `cake`, I want get the result with 2 rows and count 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the counting in a scalar sub-select which removes the need of a GROUP BY. Then you can filter on that count, to get only those where the keyword occurs

```
select id, 
       keywords, 
       keyword_count, 
       sum(keyword_count) over () as totalcount
from (
   select kl.id, 
          kl.keywords,
          (select count(distinct word)
           from unnest(kl.keywords) as u(word)
           where u.word ilike '%apple%') as keyword_count
   from keywordlist kl
) t
where keyword_count > 0
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=a40715256949f7c1009a371bfb136d29)